# mysql 3 table combination into 1 row with 2 values

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'm creating a bank application in Java using Swing.
I created a mysql table for the transaction log and it contains following columns.
[image]

So I have 2 other tables - users and accounts.
I'm wondering, how can I SELECT user.name and user.lastname from table users - WHERE transaction_log.from_user=9;

I have no idea how to even start the query or which joins to use.
The same principal goes to accounts. I want to SELECT every row which has from_account=1 while also displaying the information from to_account.

I'm completely lost. If something more is needed, I'll edit the post.

Here will be the table structure with relations.
[image]

Comment: give all three table structure with relation ...............

Comment: @IstiaqueHossain Updated the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you first query will be look like this

```
SELECT u.name , u.lastname FROM transaction_log trn
INNER JOIN user u ON (u.id = trn.from_user)
WHERE  trn.from_user = 9;
```

even you can use `LEFT JOIN` instated of `INNER JOIN`......
for second query you can try yourself... i will be help you

Comment: So in order to get all the data, I'll have to do multiple queries, right? Or maybe I should just change the database model a bit?

Comment: are you get proper data from this query ?

Comment: Yes, but the thing is that I need both from_user and to_user data which comes from the same table - users. This is a very complicated thing for me to explain as I'm pretty new to Java + MySQL (using JDBC);

Comment: for do this you need to add another ```INNER JOIN``` , but it raise performance issue....

Comment: in this particular project performance is not an important factor, but I'll try. I used INNER JOIN previously, but it returned 0 rows.

Comment: ```SELECT u.name , u.lastname, concat(ud.name ,' ', ud.lastname) as to_user  FROM transaction_log trn
INNER JOIN user u ON (u.id = trn.from_user)
INNER JOIN user ud ON (ud.id = trn.to_user)
WHERE  trn.from_user = 9;```

Comment: Thank you! This worked! And I just realized that you can use Inner Join 2 times. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

As [Istiaque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59149627/6622913) mentioned in a comment , this would be the correct query for me.

```
SELECT trn.id, fa.account_nr, CONCAT(tu.name , ' ', tu.lastname), 
ta.account_nr, trn.amount
FROM transaction_log trn
INNER JOIN users tu ON (tu.id = trn.to_user)
INNER JOIN accounts fa ON (fa.id=trn.from_account)
INNER JOIN accounts ta ON (ta.id=trn.to_account)
WHERE trn.from_user=9;
```

What I didn't realize is that you could `INNER JOIN` the same table twice. This now resolves my problem.